# Errors in listing AD groups for AD PCs

Tags: powershell, properties

I am writing a script for work and trying to determine why my code is showing errors. I am new to this coding and want to understand what is wrong.

The errors I get are from the tag .... PC listings in my .txt file.

Ex: Get-Content : Cannot find path 'F:\tag 77909' because it does not exist.
   My confusion is that when I write-host after the .Replace code it prints correctly

Ex:You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. + $Notags =$PC.Replace <<<< ("tag ", "PC")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Replace:String) [], RuntimeEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Last error I get is that it only prints out the last PC.... ID in my .txt file listing??? I am unsure why given I have a foreach loop

```
**MY CODE SO FAR:**

Import-Module activedirectory

$compImports = Get-Content "C:\Temp\temp\input.txt"
$groupExport = "C:\temp\temp\output.txt"
Clear-Content $groupExport

$Header = "PC Name" + "|" + "Group Name" + "|" + "Group Description"

#Write header 
$Header | Out-File $groupExport -Append

#get PC tag listing
$PCs = Get-Content $compImports

#For loop to change all "tag " to "PC"
foreach($PC in $PCS)
{
$Notags =$PC.Replace("tag ", "PC")
}

#loop to get information and print it out
foreach ($Notag in $Notags) {
   $computerobj = Get-ADComputer $Notag -Properties memberof 
   $computerobj.memberof | ? {$_ -match '^CN=APP.*'} `
   | % {get-adgroup $_ -Properties name, description} | `
   % {$computerobj.Name + "|" + $_.name + "|" + $_.description `
   | Out-File $groupExport -Append}
}
```

Comment: Does the text file just contain items like `tag 77909`?

Comment: Yes it does. However, I figured out my error. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least one issue here

```
$compImports = Get-Content "C:\Temp\temp\input.txt"
...
$PCs = Get-Content $compImports
```

You are calling `Get-Content` twice which would generate the error you are seeing most likely. 
Could be simplified as

```
$PCs = Get-Content "C:\Temp\temp\input.txt"
```

Your other error should go away as a result since $PCs should contain real data at that point.

Comment: Yes I see that now THANKS! and I realized why my .txt file wasn't being read through. I moved second foreach loop inside first foreach loop. It prints right.

Comment: If this answered your question it would be beneficial to mark it answered

Comment: @AlyssaCooke there is a check mark in the upper right hand corner of my answer. You could check that if you feel your issue is resolved.